# How does one make x-screensavers work with mate-screensaver?

Tags: linux-mint, screensaver, mate-desktop

I am currently using Linux Mint - Mate Edition. I much prefer the mate-screensaver lock-screen so I refuse to use x-screensaver b/c its lock-screen is just hideous.

I have learned elsewhere on the internet that one can use x-screensavers on mate-screensaver merely by editing the .desktop files. However, the image manipulating ones do not work b/c the x-screensaver daemon normally takes a screenshot of the active desktop and then hands it to the screensaver to use and therefore this does not work when using such screen-savers with the mate-screensaver. How can I make them work properly? (by taking a screenshot first and then using it)

Answer (score 1):

**Mate-Screensaver (Using XScreensavers)**

1. Download [mate-screensaver-hacks] package, unpack it and hold for later.
2. Install packages with additional screensavers:
   xscreensaver-data
   xscreensaver-data-extra 
   xscreensaver-gl 
   xscreensaver-gl-extra
   xscreensaver

   [**Note**: xscreensaver is ONLY installed to load the {.xscreensaver} file into the /home directory and to set your image directory.]
3. Run: xscreensaver to load the {.xscreensaver} file into the /home directory.

   [**Note**: Do Not start the xscreensaver daemon. I don't know what will happen if you do.]

   For **GLSlideshow**- click the Advanced-TAB in the upper left and select [Choose Random Image] then browse to the image directory you want to use and open it, then close Xscreensaver.
4. Use Synaptic Package Manager and do a Complete Removal of (xscreensaver) ONLY.
5. Open: {/usr/share/applications/screensavers} as Administrator and delete all the screensaver files. While still in Administrator mode go to the  mate-screensaver-hacks directory and copy all the new screensavers into the directory you just deleted all the old ones from, then close the directory.
6. Open Mate-Screensaver and you should have all the Xscreensavers available for use.

   For **GLSlideshow**- open Text Editor as Administrator and then open /usr/share/applications/screensavers/glslideshow.desktop .

   Look for the following entry:

   Exec=glslideshow -root

   Modify this line to instead read:

   Exec=glslideshow -root -duration 15 -pan 15 -fade 5 -zoom 75

Where:

**duration** represents the amount of time (in seconds) to display an image for

**pan** represents the amount of time (in seconds) to run the pan effect on this image

**fade** represents the transition time (in seconds) to fade between images

**zoom** represents the amount to zoom and pan as a percentage. Default: 75, meaning that 75% or more of each image will always be visible. If set to 100%, then the images will always fill the screen, and no panning or zooming will occur. Images will still smoothly fade from one to another, however, assuming -fade is non-zero.

**Note**: With the settings of -pan 6 -duration  30,  each  image will  be displayed five times (30/6), and then a new image will be loaded.  If you want a new image to be loaded at each fade, then set -pan and -duration to the same value.

~~~ **IMPORTANT** ~~~

If **GLSlideshow** doesn't load after the set amount of time, follow these instructions:

Run:

```
$ sudo pluma /usr/share/applications/screensavers/personal-slideshow.desktop
```

Enter: Password

Text Editor will open as -Superuser- and the personal-slideshow.desktop file will be blank.

In same window click-Open and select File System, then open {/usr/share/applications/screensavers/glslideshow.desktop} file.

Click: Edit and Select All, then copy and paste to  personal-slideshow.desktop file.

In the personal-slideshow.desktop file look for the following entry:

```
Name=GLSlideshow
```

Change it to a new name:

Name=*(whatever you want)*

Save and Exit

Open Mate-Screensaver and select your new slideshow screensaver. It should work just fine.

Use the same info above to adjust the settings. Just make sure you open personal-slideshow.desktop instead of glslideshow.desktop...

For **GLSlideshow**- to change the image directory open home/.xscreensaver in Text Editor. (Hidden file - mark Show hidden files.)

Look for the following entry:

```
imageDirectory: /home/*whatever*/*whatever*
```

Modify this line by replacing the current directory path with your new one. Save and exit.